# Call object's function without declaring "new"?

Tags: javascript, object

The following code below is broken all it needs to work is `var thing = new thing();`, I understand this. My question is is there a way for the below code to work without declaring new? Something in the `thing` or `something` objects?

```
var thing = function(){

    var something = {};

    something.num = function(){
        return 5;
    };

    return something;

};

console.log(thing.num());
```

Comment: Well `thing().num();` would give you 5  - i.e invoke thing and then invoke its return

Comment: @AlexK. this is cool, I like this, thanks!

Comment: There are several ways to make *thing* relate to *something* and its *num()* the best one will probably depend on what it is you want to achieve/express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this:

```
var thing = (function(){
    var something = {};
    something.num = function(){
        return 5;
    };
    return something;
}());

console.log(thing.num());
```

This will just execute that function immediately, and assign the return value (`something`) to `thing`. Your original code assigned the function itself to `thing`. If you want to keep the original function, you can use `console.log(thing().num())`.

Comment: Why not just do `var thing = {'num': function(){return 5;}};` ?

Comment: @phant0m I'm assuming that's just an example, and the actual code is more complicated. One possible reason is using closures to emulate private variables.

Comment: A reasonable assumption, +1.